# Exchange phase of 2 image's fft and reconstruct

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm having unsatisfactory image when I use matlab to exchange 2 image's fft phase and reconstruct back those 2 image with inverse fft.

Where is my code incorrect?

```
A = imread('1.jpg');
B = imread('2.jpg');
X = rgb2gray(A);
Y = rgb2gray(B);
XF = fft2(X);
YF = fft2(Y);
magA = abs(XF);
phaseA = angle(XF);
magB = abs(YF);
phaseB = angle(YF);
AF = magA.*exp(1i*phaseB);
BF = magB.*exp(1i*phaseA);
Anew = ifft2(AF);
Bnew = ifft2(BF);
```

Comment: How do you define "unsatisfactory"? What makes you think this image would look good?

Comment: I got back 2 image and there are only some black spots on them. It should be at least an outline of 2 image I think.

Comment: How are you visualizing the images?

Comment: I use imshow() for each image

Comment: That's the issue. It expects all values to be between 0 and 1. Use either `imagesc` or specify the second input to `imshow`: `imshow(Anew, [])`